# Averaging the values in while loop

Tags: java

So I have a public accessor method called gettSeconds and I have called it in a while loop as below 20 times:

```
int i =0;
double sum = 0;
double average =0;
while (i < 20) {
        call.read();
        sum = sum + call.getSeconds();
        System.out.println(sum);
        average = sum / 10.0;
}
```

So basically I called read 20 times and then I calculate how long it took to read the file each time and average the total time.But I keep getting my last time as my average instead of the actual average.

Comment: you should calculate the average after the loop is done: ```average = sum / 20;```

Comment: That case did not work either. Still getting the last value.

Comment: You'll have to show your actual code if you want someone to find your error.  I don't believe this is it (the lack of an `i++` anywhere in your loop is my reason for believing this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am enticed to change much more - but lets keep as much as possible of your original - you probably want to do something like this?

```
double sum = 0;
double average =0;
for (int i=0; i < 20; i++) {
  call.read();
  sum = sum + call.getSeconds();
}
average = sum / 20.0;
System.out.println(average);
```

Note that for your original `while (i < 20)` - the condition is always true, so in effect it would run forever. Maybe you had different intentions - in that case, please be more clear.

Comment: Yes I forgot to add i++; at the end. Thanks this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should be calculating the average after summing all the values:

```
int i = 0;
int sum  = 0;
int average = 0;
while (i < 20) {
    call.read();
    sum = sum + call.getSeconds();
}
average = sum / 20.0;
```

We can simplify this by using a `for` loop and the `+=` operator:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    sum += call.read().getSeconds();
}
int average = sum / 20.0;
```